# How can I force koa to use buffer in Strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi, koa

I have a little issue with koa, I cannot get it to work sending buffer.

provided the following code:

```
const fooFunction = async (ctx: Context) => {
  ctx.response.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
  ctx.response.set(
    "Content-disposition",
    `attachment;filename=foo.bar`
  );
  ctx.body = {
    data: Buffer.from("test")
  }
  return ctx
}
```

The http request give me the following response:

```
{
  "data":{
    "type":"Buffer",
    "data":[116,101,115,116]
  }
}
```

If I change the object affected to body:

```
const fooFunction = async (ctx: Context) => {
  ctx.response.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
  ctx.response.set(
    "Content-disposition",
    `attachment;filename=foo.bar`
  );
  ctx.body = Buffer.from("test")
  return ctx
}
```

the http response contains

```
test
```

How can I force koa to send a response like

```
{
  "type":"Buffer",
  "data":[116,101,115,116]
}
```

Without wrapping it in an object ?